# Permission denied when writing new Rasterio file

Tags: coordinate-system, rasterio

I asked this on the general stack overflow but not the GIS one. If that is against the rules I apologize:

I am writing a script to reproject rasters using rasterio and get the following error:

> Attempt to create new tiff file 'E:/MapsForTesting/Reprojected' failed: Permission denied

Here is my code bloc:

```py
import os
import rasterio
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform , reproject, Resampling 

#get working directory
os.chdir('E:\MapsForTesting')
#open unprojected raster
dstCrs = 'EPSG:32620' # the EPSG code for UTM Zone 20

def reproject(infile, outfilepath):
    #kill = rasterio.open(infile) """Attempt to solve issue does not work"""
    with rasterio.open(infile) as srs:  
        srs_crs = srs.crs
        transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
            srs.crs, dstCrs, srs.width, srs.height, *srs.bounds) #calculate transform
        kwargs = srs.meta.copy()
        kwargs.update({
            'crs': dstCrs,
            'transform': transform,
            'width': width,
            'height': height
        })
    #kill.close()# close the rasterio dataset """Attempt to solve issue does not work"""
    #os.remove(infile)# delete the file       """Attempt to solve issue does not work"""

        with rasterio.open(outfilepath.format(), 'w', **kwargs) as dst: 
            for i in range(1, srs.count + 1):
                reproject(
                    source = rasterio.band(srs, i),
                    destination = rasterio.band(dst, i),
                    srs_transform = srs.transform,
                    srs_crs = src.crs,
                    dst_transform = transform,
                    dst_crs = dst_crs,
                    resampling = Resampling.nearest)
            dst.write(reproject)
    return(outfilepath)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many issues with your code:

- Your path should be a raw path `r'E:\MapsForTesting'` not `'E:\MapsForTesting'` notice the `r`.
- `srs_crs = src.crs,` should be `srs_crs = srs.crs,` notice the typos `src` which should be `srs`.
- `dst_crs = dst_crs,` should be `dst_crs = dst.crs,` notice the typos `_` should be `.`

With all the above issues, I still could not make it work. So I started fresh from the examples written in the [documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reproject.html). You can adapt the examples for your needs as follows:

```py
import os
import rasterio
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform, reproject, Resampling

path = r'E:\MapsForTesting'

#change in_raster.tif to the name input raster file
inras = os.path.join(path, 'in_raster.tif')

#change out_raster.tif to the name output raster file
outras = os.path.join(path, 'out_raster.tif')

dst_crs = 'EPSG:32620'

def reproject_ras(infile, outfile):

    with rasterio.open(infile) as src:
        transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
            src.crs, dst_crs, src.width, src.height, *src.bounds)
        kwargs = src.meta.copy()
        kwargs.update({
            'crs': dst_crs,
            'transform': transform,
            'width': width,
            'height': height
        })
    
        with rasterio.open(outfile, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
            for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
                reproject(
                    source=rasterio.band(src, i),
                    destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                    src_transform=src.transform,
                    src_crs=src.crs,
                    dst_transform=transform,
                    dst_crs=dst_crs,
                    resampling=Resampling.nearest)
    return(outfile)

reproject_ras(inras, outras)
```

I believe using the above code will do the job.

Comment: Thank you. Yes this works!